# How to select different elements using Selenium?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I had to start using Selenium recently as a website that I crawled had updated to javascript, after seeking some advise here Selenium was recommended as the program of choice in this situation.

Using Selenium I am now able to crawl the website and "roughly" get what I want but I would like some guidance on how to select the different elements that I gathered when I crawled the Table.
For example, When I use J-Soup to gather the data I get the Whole table like so:

```
docVTS = Jsoup.connect("http://********************").timeout(10000).get(); 
                Elements table = docVTS.select("table.dynlist");
```

Then I can gather the different parts of that table like this:

```
                Elements number = table.select("td:eq(0)");
                  vtsInt = number.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < vtsInt; i++) {

                   ships = table.select("td:eq(1)").get(i).text().replace("&nbsp","");
                       arr_ships.add(ships);

                   dwt = table.select("td:eq(3)").get(i).text().replace("&nbsp","");
                       arr_dwt.add(dwt);
```

Is it possible to do the same with Selenium?

I currently have:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='cphBody_Report_grid']")).getText();
```

This gets the table but I am unsure as to how I could select the different parts of the table like I do in j-soup.
I would welcome any advice. Thank you.

Edit: I found this CookBook for Selenium and selectors in general and found it rather helpful when starting with selenium: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/

Comment: Why not use Jsoup to parse, etc. after you navigate to the page with Selenium (if you're already familiar with Jsoup?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question. Yes this is possible.

Get table row tds

```
List<WebElement> rowData = findElements(By.cssSelector("table tr td"));

For (WebElement we : rowData) {
    //do something with the tds
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have in the mean time been able to select the table data cell by cell, but do you know how to select the individual contents of each cell? I have updated my question, Thanks. Hold that, I will ask a new question.

Comment: Calling .text() on the element returns the string as text in the td

Comment: A sample implemantation is here https://github.com/alicakil/SeleniumCrawler